# XMLHttpRequest cannot load . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: angularjs, api

```
angular.module('footApplication.services', [])
    .factory('AllBet', function ($resource) { 
        return $resource('http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/1/fixtures');  
    });

.controller("GetAllBet",function($scope,$http){
    $http.get("https://edg.epa.gov/data.json").success(function(data){
        $scope.teams=data.data;
        console.log($scope.teams.conformsTo);
    });    
});
```

Comment: The site is not allowing you to do this, look at the Ajax examples @ api.football-data.org, you are required to provide a X-Auth-Token header

Comment: Go and look at the hundreds of other questions, with answers for this exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register to allow CORS:

[image]

Comment: how I can add  API token to the code when I consume the Web service